# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame

Tags: contacts, error

We recently moved our database to a new server, but when adding a new contact we now get this error:
[image]

This is what our server admin found:

[20-Sep-2020 21:53:47 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find
active frame

thrown in
/home/other/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php
on line 93

What should we do to fix this?

Comment: If you turn on debugging you should get a full backtrace which might have a more useful error (Administer->System Settings->debugginng)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the error signals that there is an uncompleted transaction somewhere. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/transactions/